# Doubts regarding abstract algebraical sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the sets A, B, C ⊆ U, prove the following equality applying the
laws of set algebra: $$A - \left(A \cap B \cap C^c\right) = A \cap \left(B \cap C^c\right)^c$$
And this is what I have done:

Part 1 $$A - \left(A \cap B \cap C^c\right)$$
$$A \cap \left(A \cap B \cap C^c\right)^c  = By The Definition Of Subtraction$$
$$A \cap A^c \cup B^c \cup C                 = By Morgan's Rule$$
$$\varnothing \cup B^c \cup C                = By Identity's Rule$$
$$B^c \cup C                                 =By Identity's Rule$$
Part 2 $$A \cap \left(B \cap C^c\right)^c$$
$$A \cap B^c \cup C                   = By Morgan's Rule$$

As you can see, I didn't manage to prove the equality. So, what did I do wrong?

P.S. In case that you think that something that I wrote sounds somewhat weird, I translated this from Spanish.

Comment: You need to add some parentheses at appropriate places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\setminus (A\cap B \cap C^c)= A\cap (A\cap B \cap C^c)^c= \text{(Set Difference Law)}$$
$$=A\cap (A^c\cup B^c \cup C)=\text{(De Morgan Law)}$$
$$=(A\cap A^c)\cup (A\cap B^c) \cup (A\cap C)=\text{(Distributive Law)}$$
$$=\emptyset \cup  (A\cap B^c) \cup (A\cap C)=\text{(Complement Law)}$$
$$=(A\cap B^c) \cup (A\cap C)=\text{(Identity Law)}$$
$$=A\cap (B^c \cup C)=\text{(Distributive Law)}$$
$$=A\cap (B \cap C^c)^c\text{(Complement Law)}$$

Comment: Could you please state which theorems you applied to reach the solution in the order that you applied them?